# elastic search by day aggregation, sum of two properties

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to aggregate on the sum of two fields, but can't seem to get the syntax right.

Let's say I have the following aggregation:

```js
{
  "aggregations": {
    "byDay": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "1d"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "sum_a": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "a"
          }
        },
        "sum_b": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "b"
          }
        },
        "sum_a_and_b": {
          /* what goes here? */
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I really want is an aggregation that is the sum of fields a and b.

It seem like something that would be simple, but I've hit a brick wall trying to get it right. Online examples have either been too simple (summing only on one field), or tried to do much more than this, so I've not found them helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Terms Aggregation generating the terms using a [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) :

```
"aggs": {    
    "sum_a_and_b": {      
        "terms": {        
            "script": "doc['a'].value + doc['b'].value"      
        }    
    }  
}
```

In order to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) add the following to your config file (`elasticsearch.yml` by default) :

```
script.aggs: true # enable just for aggregations
```

Comment: Thanks much for the tip. When I tried that I got a parse exception: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [aggs] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; }]", I assume that there's some configuration change needed to enable scripting?

Comment: OK, adding the config got me further, thanks! I'm getting back: "sum_a_and_b": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "368",
                "doc_count": 5556
              }
            ]
          }, (sorry about lack of formatting) but no actual value. Is there something else I need to add to the aggs?

Comment: So all your available documents (5556) have the same sum for these 2 fields.

Comment: What do you mean by actual Value. Separate vales for a and b. is this what you meant

Comment: You are aggregating by sum, so what you query is : group the items by the sum of these 2 fields, so for every document the sum is the same, this is why you have just 1 bucket.

Comment: By "actual value" I mean the actual sum of a and b; i'm not really interested in the values of a and b themselves.

Comment: @MartyKiker yes, 368 is the actual sum of a and b.